# sudo error even after using "become: yes" in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have used the `become: yes` condition in my `.yml` file. Yet, I'm getting the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"}
```

This is my Ansible playbook for reference:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  remote_user: test
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files: 
  - files/awscreds.yml
  - files/info.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Basic provisioning of EC2 instances
      ec2:
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_id }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_key }}"
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        image: "{{ standard_ami }}"
        instance_type: "{{ free_instance }}"
        key_name: "{{ ssh_keyname }}"
        count: 1
        state: present
        group_id: "{{ secgroup_id }}"
        wait: no
        instance_tags:
          Name: Dawny33_template
      register: e2info
    - name: Print the results
      debug: var=ec2info
```

Where did I go wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need `sudo` to run `ec2` module.
2. Error *sudo: a password is required* suggests that you don't have passwordless sudo set up.